# Graphic polygon layer doesn't get recognized as connected in KiCAD 6?

Tags: pcb, kicad

I have a specific header design that I need, containing 25 2.54mm (0.100") pins on one side and 25 3.175mm (0.125") on the other, connected across. The entire footprint looks like this:

[image: Footprint 1]

As you can see, the pads on the left need to be connected to the ones on the right. I tried doing this in the footprint editor, using a graphical polygon with the top copper layer, however getting it into the PCB editor I get an unconnected DRC error:

[image: Copper]

Is there a way to get around this? If I ignore DRC and actually print the board like this, will it work?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the polygon and giving it a net name of GND? This is the basic problem; KiCAD sees a piece of copper that doesn't have a net attached to it.

Comment: Is it possible to assign a net name in the footprint editor? Additionally, can I do this for every pad combination, not just the power symbol ones?

Comment: There is a white "ratsnest" wire visible in the last photo, between 1GND and 1GND, indicating that KiCAD thinks there should be a connection there and does not see one.  Was the red copper drawn as a *graphic line* or *polygon*?  Connections go to the center of the pads (ends of the ratsnest lines.)

Comment: It was drawn as a graphic polygon _inside the footprint editor_. The polygon was drawn to connect the 4 sharp corners of the 2 pads.

Comment: I know this issue for a long time and haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: @rdtsc KiCAD is fine with polygons overlapping parts of the pads, normally the tracks don't have to cover the center of a pad to be considered connected by KiCAD

Comment: If you notice while drawing regular tracks, the lines start from the ends of the ratsnest.  Then KiCAD "hides" these stubs so the pad/hole appears correctly.  What I'm getting at is that maybe KiCAD isn't seeing these two as connected because the copper does not touch the ends of the ratsnest line (as it would with a regular routed trace.)

Comment: Could try a regular, routed trace between these points, then lay a polygon overtop of it.

Comment: @rdtsc from my experience the problem is exactly what Andy said: as long as the polygon has no net, it will not be considered a connection. It may even give an error because the polygon (which has no net information) is too close to the pads (which are part of a net). The problem would be solved if all pads with the same ID were assigned to the same net automatically, but to my knowledge, KiCAD can't be forced to do this...

Comment: I believe this is intentional; graphic polygons that are part of the footprint are ignored because otherwise net ties would throw DRC errors constantly. (They're working on replacing the net tie system with something more practical, but until then, we have this awkward workaround.)

Comment: You can make the polygon into a part of one of the pads, though, using the custom  pad shape system. That might fix your problem?

Comment: I vaguely recall creating a rectangular pad with a beveled corner, I think in KiCAD 4.  Think it required three polygons; two rectangles and a right-triangle.  Been so long, I forget how I did it.  Believe all three of them were assigned the same net.

Comment: @Heart indeed, I tried the custom pad shape with polygons, and while that does indeed work and triggers no DRC errors, it does not fit my current application. But I have tested it and it does work.